# OpenCV TypeError: Expected on iteration files in directory Python

Tags: python, directory, opencv

I have a problem with convert files in the directory. It gives me a TypeError, and I'm not sure how to fix it.
Below I am pasting my code along with the output.

```
directory = './Input/'
for filename in os.scandir(directory):

    print(filename)
    print(type(filename))

    # image = cv2.imread(filename)
    result = sr.upsample(filename)
    cv2.imwrite("./Output/image.png", result)
```

my output:

```
<DirEntry '1.png'>
<class 'posix.DirEntry'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-e9096dfd223e> in <module>()
     28 
     29     # image = cv2.imread(filename)
---> 30     result = sr.upsample(filename)
     31     # cv2.imwrite("./Output/image.png", result)
     32     # else:

TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upsample function takes the image Mat, not the DirEntry or the path. you need to read the image first.

maybe try:

```
directory = './Input/'
for filename in os.scandir(directory):
    if (filename.path.endswith(".jpg") or filename.path.endswith(".png")):
        print(filename.path)
        image = cv2.imread(filename.path)
        result = sr.upsample(image)
        cv2.imwrite("./Output/image.png", result)
```